# 'The following app is part of another app' alert when uninstalling an app

Tags: android

I installed my signed apk on android emulator and when I tried to uninstall it, android made a dialog and said

***MyApp*** is part of the following app: **MyApp**

*do you want to uninstall this app?*

I wanna know what makes android to make this dialog because my app(**MyApp**) is not part of another app

and this is my **Manifest.xml**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.app.driver.android">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.sec.android.provider.badge.permission.WRITE" />

    <application
        android:name=".global.Application"
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="false"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity android:name=".activity.SplashActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.HomeActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data
                    android:host="home_activity"
                    android:scheme="app_driver" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.ActivationActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.LoginActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.NoInternetConnectionActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.ProfileActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme2"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.MapActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.RequestActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />


    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Are you sure that your app has not the same package name as your previous installed one?

Comment: @JagarYousef i don't know what u mean exactly , but there is know other app installed on emulator with the same package name

Comment: Add you manifest xml in the question

Comment: @JagarYousef I Added

Answer (score 1):

Same problem. But I resolved it after I located that there was 2 activities that has different labels.